# How to delete object from firebase as well when the cardview is swpied in recyclerview>

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview list which is also stored in firebase database and I want that when I swipe the cardview, it deletes that from recyclerview as well as from firebase, but I don't know how to delete it from firebase.

Code:-

```
    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback( 0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

            contactList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Contact Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Adapter:

```
class saveContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<saveContactAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<SaveContact> contactList;

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;

    public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), AllUsersActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}

public saveContactAdapter(ArrayList<SaveContact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}
//Context context;

// LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item,null);
@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_item,viewGroup,false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final saveContactAdapter.ExampleViewHolder contactViewHolder, final int i) {
    final SaveContact currentItem = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getmText1());
    contactViewHolder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getmText2());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}
```

}
[The highlighted part means one cardview and the next is the other cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqGWi.png)

how do I delete this information from firebase as well when I swipe the cardview?

Answer (score 0):

Use this and replace "" with your values.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("").child("").removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (!cu.getPfp().equals("Default")) {
                            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(cu.getUid() + ".jpg").delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                      //Success
                                    } else{
                                       // Error
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```